# convert csv file with json data inside to a column, rows table in 2nd csv file

Tags: json, ruby, csv

Ruby newbtard here...

I have an csv file (logevents.csv) that has a "message" column.
The "message" column contains rows of json data.
Using Ruby, I'd like to convert the json data's name:value pairs to columnname:rowvalue in a 2nd csv file.
Here's the 1st row of the csv file:

message
"{""version"":""0"",""id"":""fdd11d8a-ef17-75ae-cf50-077285bb7e15"",""detail-type"":""Auth0 log"",""source"":""aws.partner/auth0.com/website-dev-c36bb924-cf05-4a5b-8400-7bdfbfe0806c/auth0.logs"",""account"":""654654277766"",""time"":""2024-03-27T12:30:51Z"",""region"":""us-east-2"",""resources"":[],""detail"":{""log_id"":""90020240327123051583073000000000000001223372067726119722"",""data"":{""date"":""2024-03-27T12:30:51.531Z"",""type"":""seacft"",""description"":"""",""connection_id"":"""",""client_id"":""v00a8B5f1sgCDjVhneXMbMmwxlsbYoHq"",""client_name"":""Website Dev"",""ip"":""32.174.36.217"",""user_agent"":""Someday v1.10.3"",""details"":{""code"":""******************************************5kW""},""hostname"":""website-dev.us.auth0.com"",""user_id"":""auth0|648a230ee5ad48ee2ebfb212"",""user_name"":""don.collins+dev@website.com"",""auth0_client"":{""name"":""omniauth-auth0"",""version"":""2.6.0"",""env"":{""ruby"":""2.6.5"",""rails"":""6.1.7.4""}},""$event_schema"":{""version"":""1.0.0""},""log_id"":""90020240327123051583073000000000000001223372067726119722""}}}"

For each row, I'd like above to be written to another csv file but with the name:value pairs pivoted into column:rowvalue with a "," (comma) as the delimiter for the column names and row values, ala:

version,id,detail-type,source,account ....etc
0,fdd11d8a-ef17-75ae-cf50-077285bb7e15,Auth0 log,aws.partner/auth0.com/website-dev-c36bb924-cf05-4a5b-8400-7bdfbfe0806c/auth0.logs,654654277766 ....etc

I have been trying to accomplish this via this ruby script (runtimetest.rb):

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

CSV.open("C:/Ruby/dev/logevents2.csv", "w") do |csv| #open new file for write
  JSON.parse(File.open("C:/Ruby/dev/logevents.csv").read).each do |hash|  #open json to parse
    csv << hash.values   #write value to file
  end
end
```

But at runtime the csv file contents (logevents.csv) are written on screen with "unexpected token" message:

C:\Users\dclad>runtimetest.rb

C:/Ruby32-x64/lib/ruby/3.2.0/json/common.rb:216:in `parse': unexpected token at '"version"":""0"",""id"":""fdd11d8a-ef17-75ae-cf50-077285bb7e15"",""detail-type"":""Auth0 log"",""source"":""aws.partner/auth0.com/trulab-dev-c36bb924-cf05-4a5b-8400-7bdfbfe0806c/auth0.logs"",""account"":""654654277766"", ........

Tried this, I have been trying to accomplish this via this ruby script (runtimetest.rb):

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'

CSV.open("C:/Ruby/dev/logevents2.csv", "w") do |csv| #open new file for write
  JSON.parse(File.open("C:/Ruby/dev/logevents.csv").read).each do |hash|  #open json to parse
    csv << hash.values   #write value to file
  end
end
```

Was expecting output to be column, row table in 2nd csv:

version,id,detail-type,source,account ....etc
0,fdd11d8a-ef17-75ae-cf50-077285bb7e15,Auth0 log,aws.partner/auth0.com/trulab-dev-c36bb924-cf05-4a5b-8400-7bdfbfe0806c/auth0.logs,654654277766 ....etc

I may be going about this all wrong.
Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Best Regards,
Donald

---

### UPDATE

I was able to get ruby to parse out a single record json file such that it would write the json name and value pairs (and nested pairs too) to a second file as a header and row .csv file.

```
require 'csv'
require 'json'


# An attempt to figure out what a row will look like
def array_from(json)
  queue, next_item = [], json
  while !next_item.nil?

    return next_item if next_item.is_a? Array

    if next_item.is_a? Hash
      next_item.each do |k, v|
        queue.push next_item[k]
      end
    end

    next_item = queue.shift
  end

  return [json]
end


# try to build header columns for the nested elements
def flatten(object, path='')
  scalars = [String, Integer, FalseClass, TrueClass]
  columns = {}

  if [Hash, Array].include? object.class
    object.each do |k, v|
      new_columns = flatten(v, "#{path}#{k}|") if object.class == Hash
      new_columns = flatten(k, "#{path}#{k}|") if object.class == Array
      columns = columns.merge new_columns
    end

    return columns
  elsif scalars.include? object.class
      # Remove trailing slash from path
      end_path = path[0, path.length - 1]
      columns[end_path] = object
      return columns
  else
    return {}
  end
end


json = JSON.parse(File.open('logevent.json').read)
in_array = array_from json

out_array = []
in_array.each do |row|
  out_array[out_array.length] = flatten row
end

headers_written = false
CSV.open('logevent.csv', 'w') do |csv|
  out_array.each do |row|
    csv << row.keys && headers_written = true if headers_written === false
    csv << row.values
  end
end
```

Here is the contents of the input file, "logevent.json":

```
{
  "Message": [
{
    "version": "0",
    "id": "fdd11d8a-ef17-75ae-cf50-077285bb7e15",
    "detail-type": "Auth0 log",
    "source": "aws.partner/auth0.com/website-c36bb924-cf05-4a5b-8400-7bdfbfe0806c/auth0.logs",
    "account": "654654277766",
    "time": "2024-03-27T12:30:51Z",
    "region": "us-east-2",
    "resources": [],
    "detail": {
        "log_id": "90020240327123051583073000000000000001223372067726119722",
        "data": {
            "date": "2024-03-27T12:30:51.531Z",
            "type": "seacft",
            "description": "",
            "connection_id": "",
            "client_id": "v00a8B5f1sgCDjVhneXMbMmwxlsbYoHq",
            "client_name": "Website Dev",
            "ip": "3.17.36.227",
            "user_agent": "JohnDoe v1.10.3",
            "details": {
                "code": "******************************************5kW"
            },
            "hostname": "website.us.auth0.com",
            "user_id": "auth0|648a230ee5ad48ee2ebfb212",
            "user_name": "john.doe+dev@website.com",
            "auth0_client": {
                "name": "omniauth-auth0",
                "version": "2.6.0",
                "env": {
                    "ruby": "2.6.5",
                    "rails": "6.1.7.4"
                }
            },
            "$event_schema": {
                "version": "1.0.0"
            },
            "log_id": "90020240327123051583073000000000000001223372067726119722"
        }
      }
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: probably you need to try use JSON.parse separately for each row's value

Comment: Hi Anton, Thank you for the suggestion!  I will see if I can get JSON.parse working first for a single row before adding other complications to the script.
Best Regards, Donald